# How to take a difference between two DATETIME columns in standard SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I am trying to take the difference between two consecutive rows using the DateTime column field. When taking the difference I get an error message saying difference can only be taken for int64, float64 or numeric values.

I tried converting DateTime to String and then to int64/float64 using the guide for casting in the link below but get invalid entries error.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules

Is there a way to take a difference for DateTime values? The values are like **12-03-04 00:00:000 EST**?

Comment: Have you tried datediff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the difference between 2 `DATETIME`, then the correct answer is `DATETIME_DIFF`:

```sql
SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME "2010-07-07 10:20:00",
  DATETIME "2008-12-25 15:30:00", DAY)

# 559
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_diff